# jQuery animate makes a div jump in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a strange issue that only affects Firefox.
In my dev [website](http://shoutkey.com/many), I have this jQuery code:

```
  jQuery('body').on('click', '.sidebar-toggle', function(e){
    if (sidebarStatus == "OFF") {
      jQuery('.panel-sidebar').animate({
        marginLeft: "0px"
      }, 400);
      jQuery('.products-listing-contents').animate({
        marginLeft: "200px",
        width: '-=200px',
        'padding-right' : 0
      }, 400);

setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery('.products-listing-contents').css("width","calc(100% - 200px)");
}, 420);

      sidebarStatus = "ON";
    }
    else {
      jQuery('.panel-sidebar').animate({
        marginLeft: "-184px"
      }, 400);
      jQuery('.products-listing-contents').animate({
        marginLeft: "15px",
        width: '100%',
        'padding-right' : "15px"
      }, 400);
      sidebarStatus = "OFF";
    }
    setCookie('sidebarStatus', sidebarStatus, 9999999);
  });
```

What it basically does is pushing a left sidebar to the left and right while adjusting the content width that appears to the left of it.
It works fine in IE11 and Chrome, but in FF the content area jumps to the bottom and back up whenever I click the slide toggle.

I have been trying to adjust the numbers, but that doesn't help. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: May be related to Firefox problem with animation on width. Try using min-width. can you give JSFiddle example?

Comment: @Itamar - even better, there is a direct link to the dev website in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with `setTimeout` in FF before. In your case try to avoid using `setTimeout` and it might just work.

You don't have to call a `setTimeout` to invoke something after the Animation ends. There is a built in callback for that. You can write a callback function with a comma after the timedelay. Check if that helps. Even if it doesn't help with your problem doing like given below is definitely better practice than using an async like `setTimeout`.

Like this:

```
if (sidebarStatus == "OFF") {
  jQuery('.panel-sidebar').animate({
    marginLeft: "0px"
  }, 400);
  jQuery('.products-listing-contents').animate({
    marginLeft: "200px",
    width: '-=200px',
    'padding-right' : 0
  }, 400, function(){
      jQuery('.products-listing-contents').css("width","calc(100% - 200px)");
  });

  sidebarStatus = "ON";
}
```

Comment: I have already tried to remove those 3 lines of `setTimeout` but that didn't help unfortunately, you can try this on my dev site, using the FF developer tool I think. By the way, the issue happens also when closing the sidebar, there is no `setTimeout` there.

Comment: I just checked the webpage in Firefox. It's working. It is not jumping to the bottom and back up.

Comment: Okay I see it now. Sorry. I thought the sidebar is jumping up and down. Didn't notice the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use css transitions. Much easier and cleaner than using jQuery.

```js
 $("#sidebar-container").on("click", function () {
   $(this).toggleClass('maximized-sidebar-container');
   $("#content-container").toggleClass('minimized-content-container');
 });
```

```css
#application-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: -160px;
  width: 170px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: #0F0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 350ms left ease-out;
  z-index: 3;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.maximized-sidebar-container {
  left: 0px !important;
}
#content-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #808080;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 350ms left ease-out;
  z-index: 0;
}
.minimized-content-container {
  left: 170px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="application-container">
  <div id="sidebar-container"></div>
  <div id="content-container">Content</div>
</div>
```